# DelayBind when to use?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I don't understand what is a usecase for DelayBind function. I can simply use

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<Activity, ViewModel();
```

but why and when I should use

```
this.DelayBind(() => { var set = this.CreateBindingSet<Activity, ViewModel() }
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DelayBind` is used when you want the bindings to be applied every time the DataContext changes as you can see [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/b8b860e63f7dfd445231308cf20ced0d56ae6e75/MvvmCross/Core/Binding/BindingContext/MvxBindingContext.cs#L223). The mainly use is to bind list items such as a `MvxTableViewCell` because it knows **when** its binding should be applied and *"refreshed"* e.g.:

```
public partial class MonkeyCell : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("MonkeyCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;

    static MonkeyCell()
    {
        Nib = UINib.FromName("MonkeyCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    }

    protected MonkeyCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

        var imageViewLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => monkeyImage);

        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MonkeyCell, Monkey>();
            set.Bind(imageViewLoader).To(m => m.Image);
            set.Bind(nameLabel).To(m => m.Name);
            set.Bind(originLabel).To(m => m.Location);
            set.Bind(descriptionLabel).To(m => m.Details);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }
}
```

Source and the full example: [Binding lists with iOS and MvvmCross](https://www.marcbruins.nl/xamarin-ios-list-with-mvvmcross)

Comment: thank you, i thought mvvmcross bindings was working more like in wpf. where you can change the datacontext and bindings will be applied without extra calls.